# The specialty-beers tag needs some love

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag, [specialty-beers](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specialty-beers), which seems to be quite the hodge-podge:

- Questions about "themes": [Band Beers? In your counrty](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/band-beers-in-your-counrty), [Which beer or beers are associated with Lent?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/which-beer-or-beers-are-associated-with-lent), [What other beer brands began as fictional but eventually became real?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/what-other-beer-brands-began-as-fictional-but-eventually-became-real)
- Questions about special ingredients or processes: [Do kosher beers exist?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/do-kosher-beers-exist), [What are some of the most common ingredients used in gluten-free beers?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4811/what-are-some-of-the-most-common-ingredients-used-in-gluten-free-beers), [Other Jalapeño beers?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4770/other-jalape%c3%b1o-beers), [Beer with honey, beer with cinnamon](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/beer-with-honey-beer-with-cinnamon)
- Questions that don't seem to be specific to *specialty* beers: [Beer Clubs Online](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4594/beer-clubs-online), [Eat bread before drink beer make you drunk less?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4595/eat-bread-before-drink-beer-make-you-drunk-less), [How to chill a 30cl bottle to "cellar" temperature?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3395/how-to-chill-a-30cl-bottle-to-cellar-temperature), [Who made commercialization of beer possible](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/who-made-commercialization-of-beer-possible), [Beer-A-Day (Free Online) Calendars](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/beer-a-day-free-online-calendars)

There are more; I'm not trying to catalogue the entire tag here.

We probably need to retag some of these, and maybe we should be creating other tags.  We already have [trappist](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trappist) and [hefeweisen](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hefeweisen), for example; I'm surprised we don't yet have "belgian".  I think there *is* a place for a "specialty-beers" tag, but the current state of the tag seems wrong.

What should this tag be about?  (It has no wiki now.)  Do we need additional tags in this space?  Which ones?

Comment: My 2 cents...This tag should go away.  It's too open to interpretation, and more specific tags will serve the site better.

Comment: @Xander I agree.  Sometimes it means micro-brews, sometimes it means Belgians, sometimes it means others... but what should we do with the oddball questions like kosher, gluten-free, chipotle?  An "ingredients" tag, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

We should eliminate this tag.  Some of these questions are about specific types of beers and should be so tagged.  Some are about unusual ingredients and maybe we should create an [ingredients](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ingredients) tag.  I don't see a unifying theme for the questions in the last bullet, but they're sure not about specialty beers.